# Help with this exponential random variable

Tags: probability, statistics

The question is
[image]

(a) Probability of an external hard drive lasts less than 5 years? What is the probability of it lasting between 4 and 8 years?
This being an exponential random variable my thought process is this, if it is less than 5 years, that would mean that
 $α=1−e^{−.1qα}$ 
 $e^{−.1qα}=1−α $
 $−.1q_{α}=  log_{e}(1−α)$ 
 $q_{α}=\frac{−log_{e}(1−α)}{.1}$ 
 I am then stuck after getting here, I am unsure how to incorporate the less than 5 years and lasting between 4 and 8. And for example, say I am paranoid, I buy two hard drives, would the probability of them lasting less than 5 years be my answer to (a) multiplied by 2? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of the CDF,$ F(y=5\text{ years})=P(X\leq 5\text{ years} )=1-e^{-0.1\times 5}=1-e^{-0.5}=0.39$

Then, the probability of it lasting between $4$ and $8$ years is :
$$P(4\leq X\leq 8)=F(8)-F(4)=e^{-0.1\times 4}-e^{-0.1\times 8}=0.22 $$

For your last question, if you bought 2 hard drives, the probability that both of them last less than $5$ years is the square of the first result, not the probability multiplied by $2$, so it would be $0.15 $

Comment: So would the expected value be (b-a)^2/12? what would be b and a in this case?

Comment: the expected  value of what ?

Comment: expected value of X, since its a uniform random variable?

Comment: it is an exponential random variable as stated in your question, so the expected value is $0.1$